# jQuery: simple Lightbox speed of transition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this jQuery library named [Simple Lightbox](https://simplelightbox.com).

Now I need to change animationSpeed property from 250 to 150.

My code looks like this and not working to change animationSpeed

**My code:**

```
var lightbox1 = $('.homegallery a').simpleLightbox({
    int animationSpeed = 250
});
```

Comment: Have you tried with `animationSpeed: 250`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options parameter is expected to be an object. So instead of

`int animationspeed = 250`

you should write

`animationspeed: 250`

So your full code would look like this:

```
var lightbox1 = $('.homegallery a').simpleLightbox({
   animationSpeed: 250,
});
```

By the way, there is no `int` in javascript, only `var`, `let` and `const`. Javascript does not care about what type you add to a variable.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `int` and `=` from your object.

**Try This**:

```
var lightbox1 = $('.homegallery a').simpleLightbox({animationSpeed: 150});
```

**Reason**:
You want to define a property in object and what you're doing is something called declaration of variable. You need to start reading about objects in JavaScript.